# JT gravity metric - solution to the dilaton equations of motion

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, topology, research-level

I am reading [Closed universes in two dimensional gravity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2402.00098.pdf) by Usatyuk1, Wang and Zhao. The question is not too technical, it is about the solutions to the equations of motion that result from the variation of the JT action with respect to the dilaton field. The action given in this paper is
$$I[g,\Phi]=\frac{1}{2}\int d^2x \sqrt{-g} \Phi (R+2)$$
which yield the equations of motion when varying the action with respect to the dilaton field $\Phi$
$$R+2=0$$
First, I couldn't help but note that the (negative) cosmological constant is absent from the Einstein-Hilbert action. Has it been set to be one? Second, the equations of motion can be solved by writting the Ricci scalar in terms of the Ricci tensor $R_{\mu\nu}$, and then by writting the Ricci tensor in terms of the Curvature tensor $R^{\lambda}_{\mu\lambda\nu}$, and then, by writting the last in terms of the affinc connection components which can, in turn, be written, in terms of metric components. Then, I will have an equation, in which the quantities to be specified are the components of the metric field tensor.

Are there some simplifications that can be made, in order to make the process of solving this huge equation easier? For instance, the authors write

> We first consider Lorentzian JT gravity on the cylinder topology $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$

Does this simplify things? And if yes, how? In addition, do we specify the spacetime geometry? Isn't it determined by the equation of motion we obtain by varying the action with respect to the dilaton field $\Phi$? This is my confusion...

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.